# How do I set default key value pairs to object instances?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm defining individual styles for use, and would like to set defaults because right now, the code is redundant.
Surely there must be a better way to approach this than to keep repeating "fontFace: 'Sen'". What is it?

```
var styles={};
styles.title={ x:0, y:0, fontFace: 'Sen', fontSize:28, color:'#7700dd', valign: 'top',};
styles.author={ x:1, y:1, fontFace: 'Sen', fontSize:12, color:'#363636' };
styles.comment={ x:2, y:3, fontFace: 'Sen', fontSize:8, color:'#363636' }
```

It'll get used like this:

```
slide.addText(myTitle, styles.title);
slide.addText(myAuthor, styles.author);
slide.addText(myComment, styles.comment);
```

Comment: but instead of writing these defaults into each and every property, and still storing redundant data, you can also apply the defaults when adding the items: `slide.addText(myTitle, { ...defaults, ...styles.title });`

Answer (score 2):

Yep - just have a default object, spread it first, then if any duplicate properties exist they'll be overridden.

```
const defaults = { fontFace: "Sen" /* All other properties */ };

styles.title = { ...defaults, /* All other properties - if duplicates, new values are set */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

If all styles use the same fontface - insert it at the parent level

```
var styles={};

styles.fontFace = 'Sen';
styles.title={ x:0, y:0, fontSize:28, color:'#7700dd', valign: 'top',};
styles.author={ x:1, y:1, fontSize:12, color:'#363636' };
styles.comment={ x:2, y:3, fontSize:8, color:'#363636' }


slide.style.fontFace = styles.fontFace;
```